# bash-if block not working

Tags: bash, shell

I have below code.The logic here is if HostList conatains any blanck entry it should set class as blank, else it should be red.Now I am getting error-

### test.sh[3]: syntax error at line 7 : `then' unexpected

can any one help me out?Thanks!!

```
     #! /bin/bash
file=./HostList.txt
{
  echo "<table>"
  printf "<tr>"
  if[%s -eq =""]; then
      class="blank"
  else
    class="red"
  fi    
    "<td" $class">%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    </tr>\n" $(cat "$file"|cut -d'.' -f1)
  echo "</table>"
}  > table.html


exit 0
```

Comment: there should be a space after "="

Comment: Is there an `echo` missing in the line after `fi`?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 yes.Please ignore it.

Comment: The string "%s" is never the emtpy string, so it's pointless to compare.  In general, if you want to check if a string is empty, it is better style to use test -z.  ( if [ -z %s ] )  note the white space, and note that this is always false since "%s" is not the empty string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bash is very sensitive about whitespace. This should work:

```
if [ "%s" = "" ]; then
```

Note that `=` is used for string comparison and `-eq` is used for integers.

**edit:**

More precisely, bash splits your original code like this:

```
if[%s # supposedly a command
-eq # parameter
=""] # parameter
; # end of command
then # keyword
```

At this point, Bash realizes that there is an unmatchen `then` keyword, and doesn't even try to run `if[%s` (which would fail too).

Comment: @grails_enthu, this is because `[` is actually a command, so it needs to be space-separated from the `if` keyword and the following arguments. You need spaces around the `=` operator because the `[` command first considers the number of arguments it has been given before deciding what to do. See the bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins and scroll down to the `test` command.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what all that HTML markup is doing in there but the `if` statement should be something like:

```
if [[ $something == "" ]] ; then
    # do something
fi
```

In other words, you need some spaces between the brackets and the arguments, at a bare minimum.

Answer (score 2):

First, your `if` statement needs some spacing, and the `-eq` is unnecessary:

```
if [ %s = "" ]; then
    class="blank"
else
    class="red"
fi
```

But more importantly, `%s` is not a variable, so you can't compare it to anything (or as pointed out in the comments, not usefully). It's just a placeholder for the `printf` command. You're going to have to be a little more explicit:

```
hosts=($(cat "$file"))
echo "<table>"
echo "<tr>"
for host in ${hosts[@]}; do
    host=$(echo $host | cut -d'.' -f1)
    if [ "$host" = "" ]; then
        echo "<td class='blank'>"
    else
        echo "<td class='red'>"
    fi
done
echo "</tr>\n"
echo "</table>"
```

(The preceding has been minimally tested.)

Comment: what line 5 is doing?it should be if [ $host = "" ]; then-- right?instaed of if [ $host = "" ]; do

Comment: You can compare %s to the empty string, but the comparison is always false.

Comment: also getting below problem--test.sh[4]: server1:  not found. where server1.com is the first entry in my input file.